# A switch in a switch

Tags: java, android

I would like to have a switch that memorizes the menu that I am currently in and then check what button is pressed so it can direct me to another activity.

Currently I have come up with this but for some reason when I am debugging the second case so: `case R.id.bt1` isn't even reached.

I have put in the variable class: `public static int currentMenu = 0;` but when I set this to 1 my debugger goes all weird.

Can anyone figure out what I might have done wrong?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int currentMenu = Variables.currentMenu;
    switch (currentMenu) {
        case 0:
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.bt1:
                    currentMenu = 1;
                    Variables.currentMenu = currentMenu;
                    checkMenu();
                    break;
                case R.id.bt2:
                    currentMenu = 2;
                    Variables.currentMenu = currentMenu;
                    checkMenu();
                    break;
                case R.id.bt3:
                    break;
            }
        case 1:
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.bt1:
                    currentMenu = 0;
                    Variables.currentMenu = currentMenu;
                    checkMenu();
                    break;
                case R.id.bt2:
                    Intent adam = new Intent(Home.this, BattleScene.class);
                    startActivity(adam);
                    Variables.currentMenu = 0;
                    break;
                case R.id.bt3:
                    break;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate answer: you missed a **break** for your outer switch.

But why did that happen - leads to the *real* answer here: do **not** even try to write such code.

This is a **gross** violation of the [Single Layer of Abstraction](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction) principle.

And the effects of that are *obvious*: such code turns **spaghetti** code the moment you close your editor. You even seem to try to change the content of the variable your are switching on the "outer" side while being "inside". Mind boggling. In a negative way.

In other words: you just started writing this code, but you can't get it correct. And the reason is because you are decided to use a **complicated** way of expressing your thoughts.

Long story short: using switches to make *decisions* and *drive behavior* is "procedural" programming. The OOP way of handling such things: use a **state** machine. And instead of asking for state and switching about it, invoke methods on objects. And those objects maybe return other objects you can invoke methods on.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks for explaining and it helped. Will try to change it but in my current java knowledge I could only think of doing this by using these switches. Still learning and now I can figure out a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fall-through in your outer `switch`. Just as you do in the inner `switch` you most probably want to `break` at the end of each `case`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int currentMenu = Variables.currentMenu;
    switch (currentMenu) {
        case 0:
            switch (view.getId()) {
                // omitted for readability
            }
            break; // <-- outer break
        case 1:
            switch (view.getId()) {
                // omitted for readability
            }
            break; // <-- outer break
    }
```